# ¿Tiene nombre el movimiento de lanzar una moneda con el pulgar?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, diferencias-regionales, terminología

Me refiero al movimiento de lanzar una moneda con la punta del pulgar para hacerla girar.

En México le decimos *volado* pero no se si este movimiento o acción en realidad tenga un nombre, y si lo tiene cual seria el verbo de ejecutar tal acción, por ejemplo de *volado*: *Volar*.

Ejemplo:

> ¿Nos echamos un volado para ver quien gana ?
>   Lo decidimos con un volado

Comment: ¿Nos puedes dar un ejemplo de una frase, por ejemplo proponiendo a un amigo que utilicen este método de decidir algo?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

El Diccionario de americanismos de la RAE recoge esa acepción de [volado](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=volado) para México y Bolivia:

> I.    1.  m. *Mx, Bo.* Lanzamiento de una moneda al aire para tomar una decisión en función del resultado aleatorio.

Sin embargo en el verbo *volar* no hay una definición que corresponda a esa acepción de *volado*.

Por otra parte, el DLE no recoge esas acepciones ni para **volado** ni para **volar**.

Para el caso concreto de "lanzar una moneda al aire para un sorteo" en España se suele utilizar *jugar, decidir* o *echar* algo [**a cara o cruz**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7NOG7x2#EySq20F).

Comment: Interesante, soy Boliviano y jamás escuché 'volado' para lanzar la moneda ('volemos una moneda para ver quien gana', nunca lo escuché). He vivido en casi todas las zonas de mi pais.

Comment: como explica, Potter, no se utiliza como verbo, el sustantivo "volado" si existe y se utiliza como y se utiliza mas bien como "hechemos un volado para ver quien gana"

Comment: En Chile, "al cara o sello"